# javascript promise all reject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a function that posts images asynchronously. I have used `Promise.all()` for this like:

```
function post_media() {
    return dispatch => {
        allPromises[key] = dispatch(upload_my_photo().then(response => {
               return response.json()
           }).then(response => {
                if(getState().process.reset){
                    // I want to reject the Promise and call the same function again
                   // return dispatch(post_media() and stop uploading photos and restart the function again)
               }
        }))
        return Promise.all(allPromises)
    )}
}
```

If I have `getState().process.reset` I want to stop uploading other photos and call the function again ?

How can I make it happen ?

Comment: Unfortunately, cancelable Promises are still being discussed (see https://esdiscuss.org/topic/cancelable-promises). So you'll need to set up by yourself a way to cancel your call to `upload_my_photo`. You could for example return both a Promise and a cancellation callback. How is `upload_my_photo` implemented?

Comment: Implementing this with promises is a bit sketchy. You might want to take a look at the more flexible  RxJS/Observable.